# Evalulating a vector function with a vector with MATLAB's symbolic toolbox

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I have a function F that is a vector of functions in n variables. For example, consider the following:

```
syms x y z f(f1,f2,f3) f1(x,y,z) f2(x,y,z) f3(x,y,z)

X0 = [1 0 1 0]';

f1(x,y,z) =  x+y+2;
f2(x,y,z) =  w-5*x+z^2-4;
f3(x,y,z) =  2*x+y^2-z-12;


F = vertcat(f1, f2, f3)
```

Here, F is a vector of three functions in three variables. In the case I am considering, I want F to be considered n equations in n variables.

I want to take a vector of scalars the length of F, like the following:

```
X = [1 2 3]';
```

and evaluate F at this vector. So something like:

```
F(X(1),X(2),X(3))
```

However, I need a way to write that without knowing n. I could find n by writing

```
dims = size(X);
```

But that doesn't solve how I parametrically evaluate F at X. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Any specific reason you’re using symbolic math here? The example you give does not require it. This would be much simpler using normal numeric syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using cells instead of arrays, you can replace `X = [1 2 3]'` by `X = {1 2 3}` (the transpose is not necessary) and `F(x(1),x(2),x(3))` by `F(X{:})`.

Comment: I'll look into this solution and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: It works! I had to also define a numerical array x to store iterative solutions for what X contains in my larger problem, but this solution allowed the indexing to work. Thanks for your help.